# copy_to_user works, memcpy fails

Tags: c, kernel, memcpy

I'm programming for device on sh4-arch linux 2.6.32 who plays video stream from UDP socket.
I've got a ring buffer in user space (called `ubuffer`) which decoder (kernel space) reads. `ubuffer` was mapped from kernel space buffer (called `kbuffer`).

Existing application (with source code) reads data from UDP socket to `ubuffer` in user space. For decreasing of delay, I've made a driver who reads payload data from UDP `sk_buf` directly to ring buffer. Right now I'm using ioctl from existing app, who sends an ubuffer to `ioctl_proc` for every UDP packet. `ioctl_proc` making `copy_to_user(ubuffer+off, skb->data+skb_off, len)` and all works fine. I need to make it without any userspace app and ioctl. So I've send `kbuffer` to my driver and make `memcpy(kbuffer+off, skb->data+skb_off, len)` instead of `copy_to_user` (that's the only difference) with the same parameters and it not works: I'm see the picture with 10% of valid pixel (some text and colors), but rest are fails. If `kbuffer` was wrong, I'll shall not see anything right, but I see something.
Value of `len` is about 100-1300 bytes.

What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I must to use some page-aligned calls?